# How can I keep quad topology on geometric models?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, faces, topology

I'm building a small modern house where the ceiling is essentially just two triangles. This makes it really hard to add edge loops and assign materials to different parts of the object. Is there a way I could model the structure so it's still comprised of quads?
[image: Current ceiling with two tris]

[image: Separate selection]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your object?

Comment: just select the edge, then edge -> limited dissolve

Comment: Yeah sure! I've added the blend file to the post.

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to do. "...makes it really hard to add edge loops and assign materials to different parts of the object..." is really not specific and could mean anything. What you do in this situation depends on what specifically you want to do next. It would be way better if you told us what you actually want to model and showed a sketch maybe. I bet you would get loads of answers almost instantly. That's how it usually goes here with clear and specific modelling questions.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. In the photos and blend file, you can see that the ceiling is just two triangles because that was the most obvious way to model it originally. Now that I am in the later stages of the scene and want to texture it, I need to assign different materials to several parts of the wall via adding edge loops vertically along the object. I would like to maintain edge flow while doing so. When I attempt to add loops along the object, the loops cut off at the top because of the tris. So I was wondering if there was a way to model the ceiling so it was composed of quads.

Comment: is it the kind of loops you want to add? https://i.stack.imgur.com/36NOY.png

Comment: Yeah. That'd be ideal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not conventional and may have consequences on the topology, but what can be done:

Select the wall bottom edges and subdivide them by 2. So that you have.

[image]

Join the vertices (select them 2 by 2 then <kbd>J</kbd> key).

[image]

Select each edge and push it to the border using <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (twice).

[image]

Now you can:

[image]

Comment: That works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This reminds me of a particular comedic trope, I think I've seen it in the Scooby Doo: they couldn't get into a house, with the door being locked and a key inside, so they broke the window and entered the house through it, in order to take the key, go out through the window and finally open the door from the outside. Maybe it's worthwile to point out the loopcuts in the last image could have any other positioning or number, otherwise on the 2nd image you're already inside the house. 

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, yes something like that!! I should have added many more subdivisions from the first image... 